# How to store endless stream to file?

Tags: linux, files, streams

- Let's have any stream of binary data (like `/dev/random`, `/dev/zero`, etc.).
- Let's have a file which size can be N at maximum.
- Let's the N is in order of gigabytes.

Is there **any elegant** method/technology-to-use/hack in linux, to achieve such **file** continuously written is at maximum N bytes long and always contains only last written data (sequentially)? This means no large moves (file to file, memory to file) just little tweaking with the last/first data blocks.

The trick I'm looking for is the file beginning moving forward and effectively forgetting any too-old content (which would increase the file size over N) - content rotation.

The desired principle could be expressed as:

```
inp = fopen(stream, "r");
out = fopen(file, "wN"); // "Special open" with maximal size of N

while (is_reading)
{        
    if (rd = fread(buff, block_size, 1, inp))
    {
        fwrite(buff, rd, 1, out); // Old content forgotten
        fflush(out);              // Allow others to instantly see the current content
    }
}

fclose(inp);
fclose(out);
```

Comment: I very, very, very much doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you can use [`fallocate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) to deallocate the data at the beginning of the file.

> **Deallocating file space**
>
> Specifying the FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE flag (available since Linux
>   2.6.38) in mode deallocates space (i.e., creates a hole) in the byte range starting at offset and continuing for len bytes.  Within the specified range, partial filesystem blocks are zeroed, and whole
>   filesystem blocks are removed from the file.  After a successful call,
>   subsequent reads from this range will return zeroes.
>
> ...

That won't change the file size reported by `ls` or `stat` or similar, but it will reduce the actual disk usage as the [file will be sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).  Trying to read from the "holes" in the file will still succeed and will return `0`-filled bytes to the reading process.

Something like this:

```
size_t maxSize = 512UL * 1024UL * 1024UL;
char buffer[ 8 * 1024 ];
struct stat sb;
int in = open( inputFile, O_RDONLY );
int out = open( outputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0644 );
fstat( out, &sb );
size_t fileSize = sb.st_size;

for ( ;; )
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = read( in, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
    if ( bytesRead < 0 )
    {
        break;
    }

    ssize_t bytesWritten = write( out, buffer, bytesRead );
    if ( bytesWritten < 0 )
    {
        break;
    }

    fileSize += bytesWritten;

    if ( fileSize > maxSize )
    {
        fsync( out );
        off_t endOfHole = fileSize - maxSize;
        fallocate( out, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE,
            0UL, endOfHole );
    }
}
```

That's only supported on XFS, BTRFS, EXT4, and tmpfs.

It also needs a lot more error checking, and may not even compile as-is.  It's also very inefficient as once the max size is reached, it will call `fallocate()` for every `read()`/`write()` cycle, and it will punch the "hole" from the beginning of the file every time.

There's also no point in using buffered `fread()`/`fwrite()` for this IO pattern.  Just `read()`/`write()` large enough chunks.